# Populate expandable listview with custom list objects in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, custom-adapter, expandablelistadapter

I have list of custom objects and I want to populate `ExpandableListView` with data of these objects . But at the custom adapter it stuck at `getGroupCount` function and it stops without error and not passing another function like `getChildrenCount`. First `getGroupCount` is working and after `getGroupCount` but nothing else. `Expandablelistview` is not showing at the screen. No error is shown and no explistview is shown, I cant find the problem, I see my list s have data. Adapter is like below,

```
public class salItemsAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

public List<ABSSALEITEM> extSetItems;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;
public HashMap<Integer, List<ABSSALEITEM>> extSubSetItems;

public TextView txtSalItemHeaderClm1;
public TextView txtSalItemHeaderClm2;
public TextView txtSalItemHeaderClm3;
public TextView txtSalItemBottomText;


public salItemsAdapter(Context context, List<ABSSALEITEM> extSetItems, HashMap<Integer, List<ABSSALEITEM>> extSubSetItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.extSetItems = extSetItems;
    this.extSubSetItems = extSubSetItems;
}
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return extSubSetItems.get(extSetItems.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return extSetItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return extSetItems.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return extSubSetItems.get(extSetItems.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View view, ViewGroup parent)  {
    ABSSALEITEM setSalItem = (ABSSALEITEM)getGroup(groupPosition);

    if(view == null)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.salitems_elv_head, parent, false);
    }

    txtSalItemHeaderClm1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSalItemHeaderClm1);
    txtSalItemHeaderClm2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSalItemHeaderClm2);
    txtSalItemHeaderClm3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSalItemHeaderClm3);

    txtSalItemHeaderClm1.setText(setSalItem.MAT);
    txtSalItemHeaderClm2.setText(setSalItem.EXPLAIN);
    txtSalItemHeaderClm3.setText(Double.toString(setSalItem.QUANT));

    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ABSSALEITEM setSalItem = (ABSSALEITEM)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if(view==null)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.salitems_elv_item, parent, false);
    }

    txtSalItemBottomText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSalItemBottomText);
    txtSalItemBottomText.setText(setSalItem.LONGEXP);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}
}
```

And I fill my data objects like

```
    private void FillExpListView(List<ABSSALEITEM> paSalSetItems, List<ABSSALEITEM> paSalSetSubItems) {

    hbSubSetItems = new HashMap<Integer, List<ABSSALEITEM>>();

    List<ABSSALEITEM> tmp = new ArrayList<ABSSALEITEM>(paSalSetSubItems);
    List<ABSSALEITEM> tmp2 = new ArrayList<ABSSALEITEM>();
    Integer tmpItemnum = 0;

    for (ABSSALEITEM tmpSalItem : tmp) {

        tmpItemnum = tmpSalItem.ITEMNUM;

        if(!hbSubSetItems.containsKey(tmpItemnum))
        {
            tmp2.clear();
            for (ABSSALEITEM tmpSalItem2 : paSalSetSubItems) {
                if (tmpItemnum == tmpSalItem2.ITEMNUM) {
                    tmp2.add(tmpSalItem2);
                }
            }
            hbSubSetItems.put(tmpSalItem.ITEMNUM, tmp2);
        }
    }

    adapterSalItems = new salItemsAdapter(salitems.this, paSalSetItems, hbSubSetItems);
    elvSalItems.setAdapter(adapterSalItems);
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use libraries which are available on GitHub. Create two layouts :- one for the heading (item on which user click and it expands ) and other one for the items which are visible on clicking the heading.

Some Libraries are

- [bignerdranch](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view)
- [anandbose.github.io](http://anandbose.github.io/android_recyclerview_expandablelistview.html)

[image]

- [bignerdranch.github.io](https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/)

[image]

- [The Expandable RecyclerView library](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Vishwesh Jainkuniya but shall i understand that there is no way to use custom adapter for list<object> for standart expandable listview?